# Bracha on  Lemon with Cloves

Tags: blessing, smell

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch brings down a minhag to make three Brachos (Eisvay, Minay, Nosson Reiach tov Lapri) on Smell on Yom Kippur to make up for The Hundred bracha a day Obligation and in some Shuls there is one guy who always brings the Lemon with Cloves stuck in it. What Bracha is made on its smell?

Comment: Are the smells distinct or is the intention to smell a combined fragrance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a Correspondence with Rabbi Belsky he said that the Brocho  is Nosson Reiach Tov Lapri.
It seems Reb Yitzchak Yosef agrees(Yalkut Yosef 216:7) as does Ginas Veradim 1:42. But the Ketzos Hashulchan 62:9 in Badei Hashulchan both agree mith Mekubal and say its Minie Bsamin.

[Source](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/Shiur.asp?id=6897)

Comment: Isn't it "Hanosein Reiach Tov Bapeiros"?

Answer (score 4):

The brakha should be minei b'samim.  In short we don't make aitz or atsbei on fruit or mixtures of spices.

If you really want to collect brakhot you could also hunt up some hadas and some basil and do all three.