# Can one use a clove-studded etrog for havdallah?

Tags: blessing, havdalah, fruits, smell, besamim-spices

I have seen a few people encrust their "used" etrog with cloves and smell this during the havdallah service. Is this permissible?

The reason I think this is a problem:

The bracha on smelling the etrog which is a fruit is הנותן רח טוב בפרות  - Who gives a good smell in fruits.

This is an entirely different bracha from the one on the cloves which is בורא מיני בשמים - Who creates varieties of spices. This is the bracha said during havdallah.

From what I can tell, when you smell the clovetrog (no, it's not a kind of monster!) you smell a mix of both the cloves and etrog.

I know that there is a concept of *ikar* and *tafel* regarding brachot made prior to eating food. Is there a similar concept regarding the bracha to make for smelling?

In the case of the havdallah bracha, would the cloves be considered *ikar*, here, and the bracha is finie for the clovetrog? Should one make two brachot? Should one not use the clovetrog at all for havdallah b/c of a doubt of the correct bracha?

---

**Update:** I see that there is a [M.Y. question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2911/5275) that answers which bracha to make on the clovetrog. There are various opinions on this. So, in answering this question, please focus on whether a clovetrog may be used for havdalah. Is there anyone that definitively answers this, or does it strictly depend on which bracha would be made? Or, because of doubts, would it be best not to use this at all for havdallah? (I see many people use it, perhaps, unaware of the "problems".)

Comment: If you decide to vote to close as a dupe, please comment why. There may be an aspect I'm not seeing.

Comment: The blessing on cloves by themselves is not 'Borei mine basamim'. The blessing for that part of havdalah specifically requires multiple types of scents, of which etrog could be one. However, from a practical perspective, the etrog loses scent fairly rapidly. It is really only being used as a holder for the more pungent smells. And this is more positive than simply throwing your old etrog in the trash.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I think the most relevant part of your comment is - " from a practical perspective, the etrog loses scent fairly rapidly". I've noticed etrog smell in this object. If, in fact, there's no smell at all, then the answer seems obviously *besamim*. Otherwise, I wonder if there's a concept of ikar / tafel when it comes to mixed smelly items. Similar to a question I asked about being in a scented forest which has a combo of fruits and fragrant herbs. (Not so strange. Near me, on a beach, prickly pears ("sabras") grow next to sage.)

Comment: @YaacovDeane it's Rosh Chodesh Kislev.  My esrog is still in the refrigerator and still smells good.

Comment: My concern would be if making an etrog-clove "pomander" is considered a potential problem of chukoseihem, since I think these types of devices were at least originally religiously significant in Christianity.

Comment: Also, I suspect the correct bracha on cloves (a dried flower bud from a flowering tree in the myrtle family) is "atzei besamim", as per e.g. http://dinonline.org/2011/06/01/beracha-for-smelling-flowers/

Comment: In fact, mixing etrog and cloves might be a good way to justify saying "minei besamim".  (See however Aruch Hashulchan who tries to justify the common practice at havdala of saying "minei" regardless.)

Comment: On second thought, since cloves are (primarily?) used as a spice in food, perhaps they also are "hanothein reyach tov bapeiroth"?

Comment: @Loewian It’s all about multiple types of reyach, as in ריח ניחח אשה להוי״.

Comment: @YaacovDeane even if they're all separately the same bracha? do you have a source?

Comment: @Loewian If you mean concerning the requirement for multiple types of scents to fulfill the wording of the blessing, see Shulchan Aruch HaRav, Orach Chaim, Hilchot Shabbat, siman 297:3. If you mean about the concept of ‘Reyach nichoach, etc.’, that is discussed in the writings of Ramak and teachings of the Ari z”l concerning the subject of scent and food, the related blessings and their kavannot. There is a good discussion in the Siddur of Rabbi Shabtai of Rashkov.